# I want to send <br> tag inside CDATA in XML. Which Does not get validated inside XSD

Tags: java, string, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I want to send 
 tag inside CDATA in XML. Which Does not get validated inside XSD. uses sequence in XSD.
My XML goes like this.

```
<hotelnotes>
    <hotelnote><![CDATA[This is <br> Hotel Note <br> End of hotel note]]></hotelnote>
</hotelnotes>
```

XSD

```
  <xs:element name="hotelnotes">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="hotelnote" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Hello, Have you tried using more strict notation (<br /> for text/html, please note de space, or <br/> for application/xhtml+xm) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the `<br>` tag is inside of the text in hotel note you can use a simple type based on the string type with a pattern restriction.

Here is an example of such a restriction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="hotelnotes">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="hotelnote" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value=".+&lt;br\s*&gt;.+" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This file will validate against the XSD code above:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hotelnotes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/hotel_example.xsd">
    <hotelnote><![CDATA[This is <br> Hotel Note End of hotel note]]></hotelnote>
</hotelnotes>
```

whereas this one will not because it does not contain a `<br>` tag:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hotelnotes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/hotel_example.xsd">
    <hotelnote><![CDATA[This is Hotel Note End of hotel note]]></hotelnote>
</hotelnotes>
```

**Update:**

If you need to accept a more generic string in CDATA you can use this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="hotelnotes">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="hotelnote" minOccurs="0" >
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value=".+" /><!-- Enter here whichever regular expression which imposes a limitation on the string in CDATA -->
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The version above just requires at least one character in the CDATA block.

Comment: I need to have both

Comment: @MalindaPeiris Please check the update which will accept <br> and also with no <br> as long as there is one single character in CDATA.